# Programmatically creating the AzureAD SAML SSO application (a non-gallery enterprise app) not getting updated by the Identifier (Entity ID) value

Tags: java, azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-spring-boot

- Using **[Microsoft Graph APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-applications?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)** I'm able to create an AAD SAML SSO application (a non-gallery application) but I notice **Identifier (Entity ID)** value is not getting populated in the AAD portal on the **Edit** popup screen, and interestingly the value is showing outside (under the "**Basic SAML Configuration**") (screenshot added).
- When I test this SAML configuration with my some Service provider tool, SSO fails and I had to come back to AAD portal and update this **Entity ID** value manually in the Edit screen, then SSO works. So I kind of notice it's because of the Entity ID is getting updated inconsistently.
- Programmatically my code looks as below, Please help with any inputs if I'm missing something to get this Entity Id value updated consistently.

  ```
    // Create Application
    Application app = new Application();
    app.displayName = "TestName";
    app.identifierUris = Arrays.asList("some uri");
    app.web = new WebApplication();
    app.web.redirectUris = Arrays.asList("https://testredirect.com");
    Application registeredApp = graphServiceClient.applications()
        .buildRequest()
        .post(app);

    // Create Service principal
    ServicePrincipal sp = new ServicePrincipal();
    sp.appId = registeredApp.appId;
    sp.preferredSingleSignOnMode = "saml";
    sp.tags = Arrays.asList("WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryCustomSingleSignOnApplication", "WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryIntegratedApp");
    ServicePrincipal createdServicePrincipal = graphServiceClient.servicePrincipals()
        .buildRequest()
        .post(sp);
  ```

[AAD portal screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qs3iO.png)

Comment: Looks like this way of approach may not be possible to fix the complication that I mentioned in the post, it is possible by using the gallery application as a template instead! and this has been answered here. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/873775/programmatically-creating-the-azuread-saml-sso-app.html